# Laravel error handler looking for views in FileViewFinder.php

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, http-status-code-404

Trying to implement a custom error handler for Laravel so that when its pushed live the 404's etc are nicer than the normal red and black screens.

I Found this which works in sense:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
  $pathInfo = Request::getPathInfo();
  $message = $exception->getMessage() ?: 'Exception';
  Log::error("$code - $message @ $pathInfo\r\n$exception");

  if (Config::get('app.debug')) {
    //return;
  }

  switch ($code)
  {
    case 403:
        return Response::view( 'error/403', compact('message'), 403);

    case 500:
        return Response::view('error/500', compact('message'), 500);

    default:
        return Response::view('error/404', compact('message'), $code);
  }
});
```

But when hitting a 404 page etc it returns:

```
Error in exception handler: View [error/404] not found. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buildsanctuary/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:146
```

If I change the view to one of my custom views / try to make the path in the Response::view. e.g.

```
Response::view('app/views/error404')
```

I receive the same error.

Or if I change change the line to:

```
View::make('a view here')
```

Then I get a white screen. Any ideas how to make these error link to a folder in my views?

Thanks.

Comment: How does the structure in your `views` directory look like?

Comment: root>app>views>errors>404.php

Comment: `errorS` `Response::view('errors/404', ...)` should work

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `Response::view()` but if it works anything like `View::make()` which I am assuming it does, it's expecting dot notation and it already knows where the views folder is.

`Response::view('errors.404')`